# Capture Alexa response json

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I would like to capture Alexa response and do some processing outside AWS Lambda. Maybe a view I would like to create with bar charts and on update it at runtime based on Alexa response. How should I do that? I can create an independent Alexa working skill.

Answer (score 1):

From AWS Lambda, you need to make an HTTP Post request to your website where your bar chart is served so that you can update your bar chart.

In order to post the response of the user, you need have an intent and then capture the user's response via slots.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Node.JS for the implementation of skill, otherwise you can find similar section of documentation for the language of your choice.

You can leverage Response Interceptor for your purpose. Follow this link:

`https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Request-Processing.html#request-and-response-interceptors`

In response interceptor you will get your response object which you can se

Comment: Sorry. This page does not exist yet. (January, 2022).